# Chords names when playing guitar with some open strings

Tags: guitar, chords, chord-theory

How do you call these chords in letter notation correctly?

First: supposedly Asus2?

-0-

-0-

-2-

-2-

-0-

-x-

Second: like B or Bm with open 1st and 2nd strings

-0-

-0-

-4-

-4-

-2-

-x-

Third: like Db or Dbm again with two open strings

-0-

-0-

-6-

-6-

-4-

-x-

Comment: It doesn't matter whether strings are open or not. All that matters is the notes that are sounding and a little bit their order from lowest to highest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call the first chord, A-E-A-B-E, an Asus2, since the 3rd (C♯) is omitted, and there is a 2nd (B) included in the spelling.

The second chord could be a called a Bsus4 chord: B-F♯-B-B-E. Again, the 3rd (D♯) is omitted, and the 4th (E) is included.

Given a root of D♭, the final chord is a D♭m7: D♭-A♭-D♭-C♭-F♭, with a minor 3rd (F♭) and a minor 7th (C♭). Note that here F♭ is used instead of the enharmonic spelling E, and C♭ is used instead of the enharmonic spelling B. But it is more likely that this would be called a C♯m7 in practice. This chord is likely to be found in context as a ii7, a vi7, or a i7 chord; for a D♭m7 these would belong to the keys of C♭, F♭, and D♭ minor, respectively. But these keys are more likely to be written as their enharmonic equivalents B, E, and C♯ minor. In these keys the chord would be a C♯m7: C♯-G♯-C♯-B-E.

Comment: @ToddWilcox-- Thanks for the edit; I guess my fingers got tired of Ctrl-Shift-U somewhere along the line.... :)

Comment: That third chord is far more commonly seen as C#m7 - C#  G#  C#  B  E. Especially amongst guitarists - who, according to several guitar sites, only use #, as b apparently don't exist in guitar world...

Comment: @Tim-- of course; I got sidetracked by OP's mention of this as some kind of Db chord and should have paid more attention. Updated answer; thanks for the catch ;)  I never understood why guitarists don't like flats; this must be guitarists who don't read, since they are all over the place in sheet music....

Comment: The only reason I can come up with is that any note is easy to make sharp on guitar - move a fret higher, whereas to flatten an open string note involves moving to a lower string. Tricky...

Comment: You can always bend the neck a bit.... :)

Comment: Ah, you've got me now. But which way??

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I am, of course, being flippant. I've only been playing for 55+ yrs, so what do I know? I know that the vast majority of big band music was written so guitar plays in flat keys. However there are at least a couple of guitar oriented sites that are bereft of flats - everything on them is in sharps, and I really don't know why. When C major triad is portrayed as C D# and G, I despair. Of course flats exist, but several if not more guitarists that I've worked with seemed only to recognise notes as sharps, rather than flats. Abm in key E, anyone? But, actually, a lot of classical...

Comment: ...guitar music was, and is written in # keys, so that the lovely open bottom and A strings can ring out, while the rest of the tune is played closer to the dusty end of the neck. Thus #### and ### become de rigour. Imagine playing that sort of thing in b, bb or bbb, holding down a 1st fret bottom or 5th string against playing something else, even on the 5th fret top couple of strings. Pretty pointless.

Comment: @Tim-- "The dusty end of the neck": I love that phrase.... Triple and quadruple sharps? I did not realize such beasts actually existed in the wild

Comment: @Tim Ah, flippancy doesn't come through well in text form.